# Is it possible to get a closed form expression for the following integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I need to solve the following $$\int_{\sqrt{c/b}}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{ax^2}{bx^2-c}-gx\right)dx$$ where $a,b,c,g$ are all greater than $0$. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.